# Best way to store and verify data onchain for offchain data integrity?

Tags: solidity, polygon, privacy, zksnark, zokrates

I have a web2 application that stores some information in database rows,
however, I would like to store this information on-chain for data integrity, particularly on polygon.

What is the best way to implement this?
I am thinking of storing the hash of each record on-chain.
then for verification, the application would hash the data offline and compare it with the on-chain hash. is this the correct approach?

I also came across [ZoKrates](https://github.com/zokrates/zokrates), will it be a better approach to use zokrates ? what is the best way to implement this on a rollup such as polygon?

Comment: Have you thought about using IPFS to store data and then storing those Hashes in the blockchain? Just like the way NFTs work!